# Hokusai and Bernice Mai timing

Tags: android-netrunner

What is the jack-out and rez timing of upgrade traps that need to be rezzed.

For instance, let's say the runner has passed the last piece of ice.  Does the corp rez Hokusai Grid after the runner has committed to succeeding at the run, or when they say they will access?

The gist of it is: when should you rez Hokusai Grid or Bernice Mai to force the user to take the net damage or trace without the opportunity to jack out?

Is it when the runner states that they wish to "continue" or "access"?  What is the official step name that I can use to make sure they have committed to whatever it is that they need to commit to so that they cannot jack out and I have time to rez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timing structure for accessing the server is:

> 4 The Runner APPROACHES the attacked server.
>
> > 4.1 [Paid abilities]
> >
> > 4.2 The Runner decides whether to continue the run.
> >         ...Either the Runner JACKS OUT: [end the run unsuccessfully]
> >         ...Or the Runner continues the run: go to 4.3.
> >
> > 4.3 [Paid abilities and non-ice can be rezzed]
> >
> > 4.4 The run is considered to be successful. (‘When successful’ conditionals meet their trigger conditions)
> >
> > 4.5 Access cards, then [end the run].

Effects triggered by a successful run fire in 4.4. There is an opportunity to rez upgrades (4.3) before this step and after the Runner has committed to accessing (4.2).

To answer your final question directly, when I play, I normally say: "Would you like to access?", then, if they confirm, I say "Before you do, I rez...". (I actually ask if the Runner would like to access regardless of what's in the server.)

Answer (score 1):

After passing the last ice protecting a server, the next step (4) is to approach the server. The runner then has the choose if they wish to continue or jack out. If they choose to continue, both players have a chance to use paid abilities and rez cards before moving onto the "successful run" trigger which is where Hokusai Grid and Bernice Mai trigger if rezzed. Then the runner accesses the server.

```
1. Runner starts, names server.
If there's ICE, goto 2.
If no ice, goto 4.
2. Approach outermost ICE.
2.1. Paid ability can be used
2.2. Jack out (Goto 6, cannot jack out if first piece of ICE encountered this run) or continue to 2.3.
2.3. Approached ICE can be rezzed
Paid ability can be used
cards can be rezzed.
2.4. Check if ICE is rezzed.
If rezzed, goto 3.
If unrezzed, and there's another piece of ICE, goto 2.
If unrezzed, and there's no more ICE, go to 4.
3. Runner Encounters Ice if rezzed.
3.1. Icebreakers can interact, Paid abilities can be used
3.2. Resolve all unbroken subroutines
...Either the run ends, goto 6
Or it continues, and there's another piece of ICE, goto 2.
Or it continues, and there's no more ICE, go to 4.
4. Runner approaches attacked server
4.1. Paid abilities can be used.
4.2. Runner decides:
To jack out, go to 6
or to continue, go to 4.3
4.3. Paid abilities may be used, cards may be rezzed.
4.4. Run is successful. Trigger abilities if any.
4.5. Access cards. Trigger abilities if any.
Agenda : Stolen (Unless additional cost)
Trash cost present : may be paid to trash
Everything not trashed or stolen is returned to server.
5. Run ends. Trigger abilities if any.
6. Run is unsuccessful. Trigger abilities if any.
```